# Passar ponteiro de ponteiros como argumento para uma função

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória

Eu quero criar uma matriz usando ponteiro de ponteiros, porém estou com dificuldade na hora de passar os parâmetros. Primeiro eu aloco dinamicamente a matriz usando uma função. E depois faço a leitura. O programa compilou, porém na hora de ler os valores ele para. Acho que o erro está na passagem de parâmetro, porém não consigo enxergar.

```
int alocaMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){
     int i;

     matriz=(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));

     for(i=0;i<col;i++){
         matriz[i]=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int));
     }
}

void leMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){
     int i, j;

     printf("\nDigite os valores: ");

     for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
             scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
         } 
     }
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     int lin, col;
     int **matriz;

     printf("Digite as dimensoes da matriz: ");
     scanf("%d %d", &lin, &col);

     alocaMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
     leMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
     mostraMatriz(matriz, lin, col);

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no `malloc` dentro do `alocaMatriz`. Quando a função `alocaMatriz` é chamada é copiado o valor de `int **matriz;` que está no `main` para dentro da função, logo a alteração dentro da função `alocaMatriz`:

```
int alocaMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){
     ...
     matriz=(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*)); //esta alteração
     ...
```

Está a alterar uma copia e não o ponteiro original que está no `main`.

Podemos comprovar isto imprimindo o ponteiro antes e depois da alocação com `%p`, assim:

```
int **matriz;
printf("\n%p\n", matriz);
...
alocaMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
printf("\n%p\n", matriz);
```

Em que na minha maquina deu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vez disso pode fazer a função receber o endereço da matriz para que esta consiga alterar o seu valor:

```
int alocaMatriz(int ***matriz, int lin, int col){ //agora com ponteiro para int**
    int i;

    *matriz=malloc(lin*sizeof(int*)); //com * alterar o valor apontado

    for(i=0;i<col;i++){
        (*matriz)[i]=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int)); //aqui também
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Chamando agora no `main` com o seu endereço assim:

```
alocaMatriz(&matriz, lin, col);
```

Com o mesmo teste de impressão de ponteiros fica também claro que o mesmo agora foi de facto alterado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tanto a função `leMatriz` como a `mostraMatriz` não precisam de ser alteradas pois não alteram o ponteiro `matriz` em si mas os valores para o qual este aponta, ou seja, o seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema está na alocação da memória. Se deseja alocar um ponteiro para ponteiro tem que declarar assim.

Além disto entenda que este é um código C compilado com C++ e não um código C++. Eu prefiro fazer C em compilador C e C++ em compilador C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void alocaMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){
    matriz = (int **)malloc(lin * sizeof(int **));
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) matriz[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
}
 
void leMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){
    printf("\nDigite os valores: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
}
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int lin, col;
    int **matriz;
    printf("Digite as dimensoes da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &lin, &col);
    alocaMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
    leMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5RaI4G). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zvcwsqqf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/PointerToPointer.c).